# How to create session-factory dynamically for int-sftp:outbound-gateway?

Tags: spring-integration, sftp

I'm trying to implement secured file transfer using int-sftp:outbound-gateway.
My current configuration goes as shown below:

```
<bean id="sftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
  <constructor-arg name="isSharedSession" value="false" />
```

```
<int:chain id="sftpGetRequestEnricherChain" input-channel="sftpGetRequestEnricherChannel" output-channel="sftpGetRequestChannel">
      <int-xml:xpath-header-enricher id="sftpHostEnricher">
         <int-xml:header name="sftp_host" xpath-expression="/fileGetRequest/property[@name='host']/@val" />
         <int-xml:header name="sftp_port" xpath-expression="/fileGetRequest/property[@name='port']/@val" />
         <int-xml:header name="sftp_user" xpath-expression="/fileGetRequest/property[@name='user']/@val" />
         <int-xml:header name="source_directory" xpath-expression="/fileGetRequest/property[@name='sourceDirectory']/@val" />
         <int-xml:header name="source_file_name" xpath-expression="/fileGetRequest/property[@name='sourceFileName']/@val" />
      </int-xml:xpath-header-enricher>
      <int:service-activator ref="refreshSftpSessionFactoryTask" />
   </int:chain>

<bean name="refreshSftpSessionFactoryTask" class="com.mycorp.filetransfer.RefreshSftpSessionFactoryTask" />

<int-sftp:outbound-gateway id="sftpGetOutboundGateway" 
      local-directory="${sftp.local.directory.get}"
      session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
      request-channel="sftpGetRequestChannel"
      reply-channel="logChannel"
      command="get"
      expression="headers['source_directory'] + '/' + headers['source_file_name']" />
```

As shown above, each message contains host, port, user and file path details.

In the RefreshSftpSessionFactoryTask, I'm setting the host, port and user details and fetching password and setting it in sftpSessionFactory bean as shown below:

```
AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(SFTP_CONFIG_FILE, this.getClass());
DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory = context.getBean("sftpSessionFactory", DefaultSftpSessionFactory.class);

sftpSessionFactory.setHost(host);
sftpSessionFactory.setPort(port);
sftpSessionFactory.setUser(user);
sftpSessionFactory.setPassword(fetchPassword());
context.close();
```

But, during the file transfer, I'm getting an exception saying "host must not be null in sftpSessionFactory".

What should be done so that the properties in DefaultSftpSessionFactory are properly set and the int-sftp:outbound-gateway to see these properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new session factory each time and completely destroying it; you are not updating the existing one.

Instead of

```
AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(SFTP_CONFIG_FILE, this.getClass());
DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory = context.getBean("sftpSessionFactory", DefaultSftpSessionFactory.class);
```

simply add `setSessionFactory(DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory)` to your `RefreshSftpSessionFactoryTask`.

Then

```
<bean name="refreshSftpSessionFactoryTask" class="com.mycorp.filetransfer.RefreshSftpSessionFactoryTask">
   <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sftpSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Store the session factory in a field and use...

```
this.sftpSessionFactory.setHost(host);
this.sftpSessionFactory.setPort(port);
this.sftpSessionFactory.setUser(user);
this.sftpSessionFactory.setPassword(fetchPassword());
```

...and you'll be updating the session factory used by the adapter.

You need to be very careful about threading, though. This technique won't work in a multi-threaded environment.